# Jenkins transferring file using publish over SSH plugin but file not show in remote development server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a running a Jenkins job by Jenkins pipeline. i wants to send an environmental (`.env`) file from my local system to my server using Publish Over SSH Plugin.

Here is my Jenkins snippet:

```
stage('Pull In Development') {
        when { branch 'development' }
        steps {
            script {
                sshPublisher(publishers: [
                    sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'developmment-server',
                        transfers: [
                            sshTransfer(
                                cleanRemote: false,
                                excludes: '',
                                execCommand: '',
                                execTimeout: 120000,
                                flatten: false,
                                makeEmptyDirs: false,
                                noDefaultExcludes: false,
                                patternSeparator: '[, ]+',
                                remoteDirectory: '/var/www/sockets',
                                remoteDirectorySDF: false,
                                removePrefix: '',
                                sourceFiles: '**/*.env'
                            )
                        ],
                        usePromotionTimestamp: false,
                        useWorkspaceInPromotion: false,
                        verbose: false
                    )]
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Then after transferring, it shows 1 file transferred.

```
SSH: Connecting from host [pasha-pc]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [stage-server-v1] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [stage-server-v1] ...
SSH: Transferred 1 file(s)
```

But when i enter the server and go to `/var/www/sockets` no `.env` file here. So am I make any mistake on SSH code.

NB: `.env` on git ignored file

Comment: can you try **/.env ?

Comment: @karthikeayan yes. But it's not working. when i rename .env to development.env then it works fine (sourceFiles: '**/*.env')

Comment: The path is relative directory, Means, generally it creates files at remote home directoy, on remote server i.e. at ~/var/www/sockets

Answer (score 3):

Please try with double `//` before `var` in `remoteDirectory: '/var/www/sockets'`.